# How to retrieve current Position of ViewPager from the Fragment itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created a ViewPager with around 7000 pages.

This ViewPager is created in my "Holding Activity" which is ViewPagerHolderActivity.

The fragments which are created and displayed in the ViewPager is called Fragment1, I would like to be able to get the current position from the ViewPager of the Fragment1, however looking at the android monitor when the application is executed, the fragment is loaded before the ViewPager so how would I be able to get the position from the ViewPager?

I have tried inserting arguments in the newInstance method of my fragment like so:

```
public  Fragment1 newInstance(int page){

    Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page",page);
    frag1.setArguments(args);

    return frag1;
}
```

and then in the ViewPagerAdapter :

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return frag1.newInstance(position);
}
```

When the current position of the ViewPager is 3660 the position shown in the fragment is 3661.

When swiping left the current position of the ViewPager is 3659 but the position is 3658 in the fragment. Why has this occurred?
I can see that looking at the Android monitor 3 instance of the fragment is created, could this be the issue? is there a work around to this?

Solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A fragment should not care what it's position is

Comment: The data to be  displayed within the fragment  depends on the position of the ViewPager, hence  why the fragment needs  to know.

Comment: positions start from zero just like index of arrays

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am aware of this, so I did try to minus 1 from the position, however the problem is that when I swipe from left to right, the position of the ViewPager is 3659 but the position shown in the fragment is 3657. However when taking 1 off the position this works fine when moving " forward" from swiping right to left

Comment: Anyone have any other possible solutions?